# Recent advancement in Haar measure

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, soft-question, research

From my personal interest I have studied *Haar Measure* and the related concept of group theory on my own. However due to the lack of an authoritative source it is not getting possible for me to know about the recent advancement in the field.

- Is there any *significant* recent advancement in the field? Or is it mostly a saturated field?
- If I want to work in this field (completely on my own) where should I look to have an idea about the open questions in the field? (BTW is it worth working in the field?)

Comment: Haar measures are a field of mathematics while group theory is a concept?

Comment: It would be useful for you to describe what exactly you mean by «the field of Haar measure».